# Avoid code duplication in a pair of almost identical base > derived classes

Tags: c++, interface, code-duplication

I have a pair of base/derived classes which are almost identical, but not quite.

[image]

I could simply copy all the code of `Base1 > Derived1` to create `Base2 > Derived2`, but that would be ugly, and would require making almost any modification twice.

**Question:** How can I share as much code as possible between the two pairs, to avoid code duplication?

---

I tried to create a small toy example that has most features of the actual problem.  I want to avoid having duplicate code for the identical part of the interface of `D1` and `D2`.  If you want to see more of the *actual* problem, scroll to the end of the question.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


//////////// 1st PAIR ////////////

class B1 {
protected:
    string name;
public:
    B1() : name("B1") { } // constructors are different between B1 and B2

    void speak() { cout << name << endl; } // identical between B1 and B2
};

template<typename T>
class D1 : public B1 {
    T x; // identical between D1 and D2
public:
    D1(const T &a) { x = a + name.size(); } // refers to base class member

    int getX() { return x; } // identical between D1 and D2
    int nameLength() { return name.size(); } // accesses member of B, identical between D1 and D2

    // differences between D1 and D2 follow:
    int add(int i, int j) { return i+j; } // different signature between D1 and D2
    void more() {} // not present in D1
};


//////////// 2nd PAIR ////////////

class B2 {
protected:
    string name;
public:
    B2() : name("B2") { }

    void speak() { cout << name << endl; }
};

template<typename T>
class D2 : public B2 {
    T x; // identical between D1 and D2
public:
    D2(const T &a) { x = a + name.size(); }

    int getX() { return x; } // identical between D1 and D2
    int nameLength() { return name.size(); } // accesses member of B, identical between D1 and D2

    int add(int i, int j, int k) { return i+j+k; } // different signature between D1 and D2
};


// this is just to test that the program compiles and works
int main() {
    D1<int> d1(5);
    D2<long> d2(6l);
    cout << d1.getX();
    cout << d1.nameLength();
    return 0;
}
```

---

The interface of `B1` and `B2` can be shared by making them inherit from a class `BInterface`.

It was suggested to me to use multiple inheritance to be able to do the same with `D1` and `D2`, through an additional base class `DInterface`.  Furthermore, it was suggested I try to use the curiously recurring template pattern to allow this additional base class to access the members of `D1` and `D2`.  My attempt at doing this follows.  I find it a bit complicated, and I would like to know if this is a reasonable approach, and whether there is a better way to do the same.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//////////// COMMON INTERFACES ////////////

class BInterface {    
protected:
    string name;

    BInterface(const string &n) : name(n) { }

public:

    void speak() { cout << name << endl; } 
};

template<typename D>
class DInterface {
private:
    D &derived() { return *static_cast<D *>(this); }

protected:
    DInterface() {}

public:
    int getX() { return derived().x; }
    int nameLength() { return derived().name.size(); }
};


//////////// 1st PAIR ////////////

class B1 : public BInterface {
public:
    B1() : BInterface("B1") { } // constructors are different between B1 and B2
};

template<typename T>
class D1 : public B1, public DInterface< D1<T> > {
    friend class DInterface< D1<T> >;
    T x; // identical between D1 and D2
public:
    D1(const T &a) { x = a + name.size(); } // refers to base class member

    int add(int i, int j) { return i+j; } // different signature between D1 and D2

    void more() {} // not present in D1
};


//////////// 2nd PAIR ////////////

class B2 : public BInterface {
public:
    B2() : BInterface("B2") { }
};

template<typename T>
class D2 : public B2, public DInterface< D2<T> > {
    friend class DInterface< D2<T> >;
    T x; // identical between D1 and D2
public:
    D2(const T &a) { x = a + name.size(); }

    int add(int i, int j, int k) { return i+j+k; } // different signature between D1 and D2
};


// this is just to test that the program compiles and works
int main() {
    D1<int> d1(5);
    D2<long> d2(6l);
    cout << d1.getX();
    cout << d1.nameLength();
    return 0;
}
```

---

Since several people have commented that this is too broad, and that the context from my actual problem is lost, below I will describe the actual problem:

[Mathematica](http://wri.com) has [a C extension API](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/LibraryLink/tutorial/Overview.html). Certain data types, such as dense or sparse arrays or images can be manipulated in C.  I am working on a much easier to use C++ interface.  The system also includes in interface generator: a lot of glue code is automatically generated based on a symbolic representation of a C++ class interface in Mathematica.  [Here's an older version of the system.](https://github.com/szhorvat/LTemplate)

I am now working on handling images.  Mathematica has [`Image`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Image.html) and [`Image3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Image3D.html), distinct expressions for 2D and 3D images.  `Image` can also have different pixel types, such as byte, 16-bit, floating point, etc.

The C API uses a single representation for all of these, including 2D and 3D images, called `MImage` (a pointer type, multiple `MImages` may point to the same image in memory).

It is convenient for have separate classes for 2D and 3D images in C++, and also to template these on the pixel type.  These correspond to the `D1` and `D2` classes above. However, in some cases, it is useful to operate with "generic" images that may have any pixel type (pixels can't be accessed in this case, but we can do other things with the images too).  This is why I also have the base classes `B1` and `B2`.

[Here's the implementation of 2D image references](https://pastebin.com/EcyiXU0E) so far (this is not done and it will change). I still need to add 3D images, which will share a lot of code.

Comment: I think this is too broad.  If you have a problem with CRTP specifically, that could be a good question.

Comment: Another thing you could try is writing D1 and D2 in terms of a template DBase, where DBase is templated on the base class (B1 or B2).  (So the tree would look like `D1` -> `DBase<B1>` -> `B1` -> `BInterface`.).  Also free functions (possibly templated), or even preprocessor macros; it all depends on your *actual* problem.

Comment: @MartinBonner  Why is it too broad?  The question is not about a concept. It is about *one particular* program.  I distilled it down to something as small as possible.   The question is how to share code between these two pairs of classes.  If the approach here is reasonable enough for this particular case, that's an answer I can accept.  I am unable to judge whether it is, and it seems much too complicated to me.

Comment: ... or mixin class, possibly templated on a something or other.

Comment: Are you sure the inheritance chain in the second example fulfills [Liskov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)? Are you sure it is actually duplicated code and not code that happens to exist twice (say a requirement changes that forces code for `B1` to change, does that also force code for `B2` to change in the same way)? Unfortunately you stripped out the context so it is not clear why `BInterface` does not include `speak`.

Comment: why you have `B1` and `B2` it they have identical functionality? Also is something is named an interface it should conform to interface standards: such class contains only public pure virtual methods and virtual empty destructor and nothing else.

Comment: I would expect `BInterface` to contain both `speak` and `name`, and similarly, I would expect `DInterface` to be templated on both `T` and `Derived`, and to contain `T x;` itself.

Comment: @nwp Why `BInterface` does not include `speak`: It was a mistake. I was focusing on `DInterface` primarily, and I made a mistake in `BInterface`. It's fixed now.

Comment: @MartinBonner I fixed `BInterface`, that was a mistake. `DInterface` does not contain `T x;` because the initialization of `x` requires `name` from `B`, and I did not know how to do that if I included `T x;` in `DInterface`.

Comment: a) You don't initialize `x`, you assign to it in the constructor.  b) Why can't you write `DInterface(const T& a) : x(a + derived().name.length()) {}` ?

Comment: In the DInterface constructor, D1 will not be fully constructed, *but `name` will be*.

Comment: @Martin Thanks for pointing that out. Yes, you are right, `T x;` can go in `DInterface`. This is a piece of the answer to my question.

Comment: @Martin Since everyone is saying that context is lost, [here's a paste](https://pastebin.com/EcyiXU0E) of the actual code, implemented for far only for *one* pair. What is it? [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/) has a C extension API. I am working on a C++ version plus an interface generator to make it much easier to use (a lot of C++ code is generated directly from Mathematica, so I can get away with writing less.)  The `ImageRef` class is like a pointer to Mathematica's [`Image` object](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Image.html), represented as `MImage` in its C API.

Comment: @Martin Mathematica also has an `Image3D` which is *also* represented as an `MImage` type (which is a pointer to a private struct) in its C API.  It is in this case not convenient to have both 2D and 3D images represented with the same class, so I want a very similar, but slightly distinct class for 3D images.  Why is there a base and a derived class?  The base class doesn't know the underlying pixel type of the image. The base class does. In some cases it is useful to work with "general" images and not manipulate pixels, so the base class is useful.

Comment: @Martin I think explaining all this properly in a question is way too much, and would get the question closed quickly.  If it's not explained in sufficient detail, I would get lots of questions about why certain things are done a certain way, even though they really aren't related to my core problem.

Comment: I disagree.  That is *much* better in the question than in the comments.  Comments are transient.

Comment: So those who voted to close this (which would deny me an answer): what would you change to make the question acceptable?

Comment: @MartinBonner I added that description in the question itself. Please let me know what else I can do to avoid closing this question.  Or should I just put it on CodeReview.SE?  I can't put the real code there are people can't compile it without Mathematica (which costs money). Also, I was so uncertain about the "solution" I posted here that I did not even consider it a solution.  Feel free to ignore it and answer the first part: how to share code between `D1` and `D2`.

Comment: [Codereview says](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) you should answer *"Is it actual code from a project rather than pseudo-code or example code?"* with *"yes"*, so unless you rewrite the question it would be off-topic there.

Comment: @nwp Yes, that's what I would have expected.

Comment: If the two derived classes just use the base class for code reuse then you should use private inheritance and optionally have methods made public with `using`.

Comment: @JustinFinnerty Thanks! Could you give me some pointers on that and the reasoning behind it?

Comment: Private inheritance is useful where classes usefully share code but are not logically part of the same heirarchy. Private inheritance blocks derived classes from being seen to have the same base class. I will create quick answer.

Comment: @Justin Thanks!  "Private inheritance blocks derived classes from being seen to have the same base class." I am satisfied with this answer :-)  I think it's clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution factors out the concepts of having a name and having a value through a base class that has a name.

If the individual components of the derived classes do not depend on each other then this kind of inheritance composition is relatively easy to maintain.

If the concerns of the base classes are interdependent then you'll have to use CRTP and marshal calls via the derived class.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// factor out common parts

struct NamedThing
{
    NamedThing(std::string &&name) : name(std::move(name)) {}
    NamedThing(std::string const& name) : name(name) {}

    void speak() { cout << name << endl; }
    std::size_t nameLength() const { return name.size(); }
private:
    std::string name;
};

template<class T, class Base>
struct NamedValue : public Base
{
    T x; // identical between D1 and D2

public:
    NamedValue(T const& v) 
    : Base()
    , x(this->nameLength())
    {}

    T getX() { return x; } // identical between D1 and D2

};

//////////// 1st PAIR ////////////

class B1 : public NamedThing
{
public:
    B1() : NamedThing("B1") { } // constructors are different between B1 and B2
};

template<typename T>
class D1 : public NamedValue<T, B1> {
    using inherited = NamedValue<T, B1>;
public:
    D1(const T &a)
    : inherited(a)
    { 
    } 

    // differences between D1 and D2 follow:
    int add(int i, int j) { return i+j; } // different signature between D1 and D2
    void more() {} // not present in D1
};


//////////// 2nd PAIR ////////////

class B2 : public NamedThing
{
public:
    B2() : NamedThing("B2") { }
};

template<typename T>
class D2 : public NamedValue<T, B2> {
    using inherited = NamedValue<T, B2>;
public:
    D2(const T &a)
    : inherited(a)
    { 
    }

    int add(int i, int j, int k) { return i+j+k; } // different signature between D1 and D2
};


// this is just to test that the program compiles and works
int main() {
    D1<int> d1(5);
    D2<long> d2(6l);
    cout << d1.getX();
    cout << d1.nameLength();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Where you want to inherit for code reuse you can use private inheritance. With private inheritance the derived classes are blocked from being cast to their base classes.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class super
{
  std::string name_;
public:
  super( std::string n ): name_(n) {}
  virtual ~super(){}
  std::string name() const { return this->name_; }
  void name( std::string n ) { this->name_ = n; }
};

class base1: private super
{
  int vertices_;
public:
  base1( std::string n, int v ): super( n ), vertices_( v ) {}
  virtual ~base1() {}
  using super::name; // make both name methods accessible
  int vertices() const { return this->vertices_; }
  void vertices( int v ) { this->vertices_ = v; }
};

class base2: private super
{
  std::string surname_;
public:
  base2( std::string n, std::string s ): super( n ), surname_( s ) {}
  virtual ~base2() {}

  // to make only one name method accessible
  std::string name() const { return this->super::name(); }
  std::string surname() const { return this->surname_; }
};

// class derived1: public base1 { ... };
// class derived2: public base2 { ... };

int main()
{
base1 v1( "triangle", 3 );
base2 v2( "john", "doe" );

std::cout << "base1: " << v1.name() << " " << v1.vertices() << "\n";
std::cout << "base2: " << v2.name() << " " << v2.surname() << "\n";
v1.name( "square" );
v1.vertices( 4 );
std::cout << "base1: " << v1.name() << " " << v1.vertices() << "\n";

//v2.name( "jane" ); // illegal code
//super *p1 = &v1; // illegal code
//super *p2 = &v2; // illegal code
//derived1 d1(...);
//derived2 d2(...);
//base1 *p1 = &d1; // allowed
//base2 *p2 = &d2; // allowed
//derived1 *p1 = dynamic_cast< derived1* >((super*)&d2); // Not allowed
return 0;
}
```

With private inheritance you cannot directly access any base class methods outside the derived class. You have two options to allow this: (1) In `base1` we use a public `using` statement to make the two `name` methods accessible. (2) In `base2` we only want one of the name functions so we write a stub method that calls the super class method (NOTE: as this is inline it should result in the same assembly code as the `using` method).

Comment: This appears to work well in every way, except one: I am not sure how to document `base1::name()` with a tool like Doxygen, without exposing the fact that `base1` and `base2` both inherit from the same class (this should be hidden from the class user)

Comment: I am not sure I can help with Doxygen. You might be able to configure it to not show private inheritance or at least hide it. You might also need to document the functions in each class separately to break the link. However, your users knowing they have a common base class is not such a bad things as they should not be able to make use of that information.